# Popover menu in landscape occupies the entire screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to create a popover.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popover"]) {
        self.popoverTvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        self.popoverTvc.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

When the user clicks a button in navigation  bar, the above segue of popover style  will be triggered and the resulting view controller has got tableview.

The problem is that,

In portrait  mode, the size of table view is as per the size of the contents available. But when I change the view from landscape to portrait, the tableview contains empty cells that are visible and hence these empty cells are blocking the ui. Why is that so? I want the tableview not to block the entire screen even in landscape mode.

Im using the following code in view did load method to resize the tableview

```
if (self.tableView && self.presentingViewController) {
    self.preferredContentSize = [self.tableView sizeThatFits:self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while, but got the same issue and fixed it by adding both

```
public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

and

```
public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

in the parent / presenting view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `size of table view is as per the size of the contents available.` give the size of popover window programmatically.

Do like follow:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"popover"]) {

        UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(180,128);


        UIPopoverPresentationController *ppc = dvc.popoverPresentationController;
        if (ppc) {
            ppc.delegate = self;
        }
    }
```

And add this below above step:

```
   - (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {

    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Comment: in landscape mode as well the size remains 180x128

Comment: whats the error you got after using ---   dvc.preferredContentSize=[self.tableView sizeThatFits:self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size]; --- instead 
        dvc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(180,128);

Comment: if i change the view to landscape, the view remains taller covering the entire screen hence it hides the ui still